# Автовыгрузка excel файлов с сайта на Asp Net Core 3-6

Tags: c#, .net, excel, asp.net-core-mvc

Интересует есть ли возможность выгружать данные с сайта в автоматическом режиме. Например, есть стол заказов, 5 пользователей сделали по заказу и эти заказы должны выгружаться каждый день в 07:00 в определенную папку. Есть ли какая-то библиотека/пример где такое реализовано?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Сервер не может управлять браузером в плане доступа к диску, это запрещено политиками безопасности, тем более браузер вообще может быть закрыт. Можете конечно написать отдельное клиентское приложение, которое будет этим заниматься.

Comment: Вы можете организовать учет заказов пользователей, с помощью определенного класса, далее сохранять такие заказы, в базе данных по мере их создания, и хранить их там. Далее вы можете создать другой класс, который по запросу условного "Менеджера", может формировать выборку,  за день, месяц, год из этих заказов,  и выгружать их в произвольное место на локальной машине. В этом [репозитории](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Rocky-Part-2)  реализован такой функционал на ASP.NET Core MVC.